# What is the difference between id, ticket_id and barcode on attendee from Eventbrite API?

Tags: eventbrite

I am looking at documentation http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/attendees/.

First of, it seems like the actual 'id' field in the json returned represents the attendee record id, as there is the actual 'event_id' field. Seems like a documentation issue.

I need a field I can use as an identifier to sync Eventbrite attendees with my records. 
The 'id' field is the obvious candidate. Can I rely on 'id' to be unique across the whole API or it may be reused from event to event?

What is the relationship between 'id' and 'ticket_id'? Can multiple attendees with diff ids have the same 'ticket_id'?

What is the relationship between 'id' and 'barcode'? One attendee can have multiple barcodes?

Would appreciate a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, I'll update the docs with some additional info.

The short answer:

- The ticket_id is the ID of a specific ticket type (General Admission, VIP, etc). A user may purchase multiple tickets of multiple types in a given order. An 'attendee' record is created for each ticket that is purchased.
- The attendee_id is meant to identify the mapping between a user and a ticket type within the event's context. A user's attendee_id will be different for each ticket.
- There should be one barcode_id per attendee_id. Barcode values can be used to check an attendee in or out of an event.

Hope that helps!
@RyanJ